# Trouble getting signed_request when developing under localhost:8080

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine

I'm making some assumptions that might be wrong but here you go.

When trying to develop under localhost:8080 (google-app-engine + java) I initially do a redirect as follows,

response.redirectTemporary("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a8080%2findex.html");

so far, so good.

I then get back a "Get" request from facebook in the form,

http://localhost:8888/index.html?code=AQDLKIRrj...

I assume that facebook determines that this is a local URL and therefore sends a "Get" in place of the "Post" that it would normally send to a public URL.

However, the only URL param is "?code="

Is this a proxy for signed_request?

Answer (score 2):

That is the normal and expected behavior, nothing to do with localhost.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ under Server-side Flow.